# can not replace when use ctrl+f

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization, output-formatting, syntax

I have a very long output, therefore, I want to find and replace some repeated expressions with abbreviations using crtl +f in Mathematica.  when I enter expressions, the mathematical can find it and mark it as eye-catching color, but when I click replace/replace all it shows not found. What should I do ?[image: Find] [image: replace]

Comment: Make a small example and poste the MMA code for it.

Comment: I suggest that you post the actual code rather than a photo. This will help other members to manipulate more easily and offer help. Also, consider providing a simplified version of the problem you are facing as has already been suggested

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 hi ， thanks， actually I have used Reduce function to solve a complex equation , but the out put is too long , therefore I want to use find and replace some long formulae with symbols like showed in picture . I did not use any code , just ctrl +f .

Comment: You can copy and paste part of the output and not the full result. Then you can also re-phrase your question with a minimal working example based on the posted code. This is what I tried to suggest before

Comment: Thanks all, I have solved, I forget adding white space when finding same patterns!